# Alternative to ls to group extensions before sorting

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls, coreutils

I'm looking for some way to modify/replace `ls` with a command that is capable of:

- Grouping directories first (as `ls` does)
- **grouping files by user-defined extension groups** (e.g., all image-type
  extensions such as png, tiff, gif, etc. together, all archive-type files together, etc)
- preserving the color information specified in .dircolors
- needs to write to stdin/out just like `ls`.
- but it need not support all additional `ls` functionality (nice if it does, though)

The key functionality that isn't already present in `ls` is in bold.  If the solution is achievable by chaining together common coreutils into some aliased `ls` command, all the better.  If `ls` can do this natively, please enlighten me, because I can't figure it out.

If someone thought of this a long time ago and implemented a `ls` replacement, that's cool too.  I've been mulling writing my own solution but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I get it wrong, you are looking for the -X option of ls.

Comment: That's not quite it.  What I'm essentially describing is a hierarchical sort, whereby extensions of a certain class (defined by the user, ideally) are grouped together, then sorted alphabetically on extension.  As an example, an ls listing of a directory that contains: directories, images of type gif, png, and, tiff, and video files of type mkv, flv, ogg, all image-type files will be listed in one chunk, all audio-type files in another chunk, etc.  In an ideal world users can define custom logical groupings.